# SQL multiple statements, INSERT not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am developing a web app and have encountered a problem. I need to insert username and ip address into a SQL database table "log" when someone tries (successfully or unsuccessfully) to login. ID, time and date are inserted automatically... 
For some reason I am unable to get it working in my login form. INSERT statement works ok if I initiate it from another form, but I can't get it working together with the SELECT statement I use for checking login credentials.

I have tried different solutions, but none of them inserts data into the table... It does not throw an error, it just doesn't insert a new row into "log" table.

Any help is appreciated. :)

```
protected void btnLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ToString()))
    {
        string username = null;
        string password = null;
        string ipAddress = null;

        SymCryptography cryptic = new SymCryptography();
        SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCommand cmdLog = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;

        cmdSelect.Connection = conn;
        cmdLog.Connection = conn;

        cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM uporabniki WHERE up_ime=@up_ime AND geslo=@geslo";
        cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log (up_ime, ip) VALUES (@up_ime, @ip)";
        cmdLog.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@up_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = tbUsr.Text;
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@geslo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = cryptic.Encrypt(tbPwd.Text);
        cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@up_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = tbUsr.Text;
        cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = ipAddress;

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            //cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();  I tried it here, but it doesn't work
            myReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
            if (myReader.Read())
            {
                username = myReader["up_ime"].ToString();
                password = myReader["geslo"].ToString();
                Session["rights"] = myReader["pravice"];
                Session["login"] = "OK";
                pravice = true;
            }
            myReader.Close();
            //cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();  I tried it here, but it doesn't work
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    //I tried to open connection again, but stil INSERT does not work
    /* using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ToString()))
    {
        string ipAddress = null;
        SqlCommand cmdLog = new SqlCommand();
        cmdLog.Connection = conn;
        cmdLog.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log (up_ime, ip) VALUES (@up_ime, @ip)";
        cmdLog.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@up_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = tbUsr.Text;
        cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = ipAddress;
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    if (pravice == true)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }*/ 
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message of some sort?

Comment: Any constraints (like unique or primary key) on the log table?

Comment: I don't see the immediate problem, but I would recommend you pull this code out of your click event and put it in another class that you could call.  It's generally not a good practice to have SQL littering your event handlers.

Comment: Is the database you're writing to on your local box? if so which version of sql are you running? If you ahve sql profiler it can tell you if you're running into a sql error. Also try returning an int value from executeNonQuery similar to this.                       int returnVal = 0;
           
 
       
                    returnVal = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

              this will allow you to see how many records were affected.

Comment: @Pieter No error message, it just doesn't insert new line into table.

Comment: @hcb No. I created the table so that it auto increments ID (primary key) and auto inserts date and time as datetime

Comment: @tayornr I will try to do that. :) It is still in the early stages, so code is not ironed out yet.

Comment: @gsirianni Yes, database is on my computer. This app is not yet complete so I'm running everithing on localhost... Will try returning int value for rows affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not executing your cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement.

Also, try opening a query window in your sql database and run the following against it.

```
INSERT INTO log (up_ime, ip) VALUES (<some time>, <test ip text>)
```

If the error lies in sql server you should be returned an error message stating if the problem lies withing SQL Server.

Also try changing:

```
    cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@up_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = tbUsr.Text;
    cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = ipAddress;
```

To:

```
  cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@up_ime", tbUsr.Text);
  cmdLog.Parameters.Add("@ip",  ipAddress);
```

Comment: Those comments are not there in actual code, so I am executing it ;) I just pointed where I tried to execute it, but it didn't work in any case. I tried using INSERT statement as it is in MS SQL SERVER and it worked...it just doesn't work when I do it from login form, will try changing parameters, thnx

Comment: I changed parameters and it works now. Will look into it why it did not work before. :)

Comment: Do you have SQL Profiler available? If so, try to see if when you declare the sql db types in C# are being passed into the sql call correctly. I rarely use that style of declaration as I used to run into too many issues for something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your connection string value is ok. Also put a break point on the:

```
   conn.Open();
```

See whether you get an error?
If not then that means your connectionstring is ok.

Uncomment this line after Try{}

```
 //cmdLog.ExecuteNonQuery();  I tried it here, but it doesn't work
```

and put a break point on it .. see whether you get an error?

Also from your code I can see that you are inserting a null ipaddress value into the table. See whether the column in your database is allowed to accept nulls??

Comment: my connection string is ok, because it connects to database and reads user login credentials from another table, also log tables accept null ip addresses...but nonetheless, I'll look into it again, thanx

Comment: I changed parameters as it was suggested in another answer and executed sql command after try as you suggested and it works now

Answer (score 0):

The using statement will clean up the connection in the garbage collection process which happens at an indeterminable time. This is why 1 of the orders of execution you've tried doesn't work (the connection may not be usable). Suggest you do either:

1. Both operations within 1 using (connection), make sure you close the connection in a finally() block and re-init your command against the newly opeend connection.
2. Have 2 different connections conn1 and conn2 and perform the separate operations in each.

EDIT: I have re-read and you say no errors occur? - try checking the result of ExecuteNonQuery (it returns an integer to show the number of rows that have been affected - if this is zero there is a problem with your insert statement).